# i have two columns in a dataframe one has column name and other has no column name how can i name them both on python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

Input

```
 Fruit 
    Apple   55
    Orange  43
```

Output

```
Fruit   Count
Apple   55
Orange  43
```

I need to rename columns accordingly please help

Comment: So need `df.columns = ['Fruit','Count']` ? Or `df = df.reset_index)` first ?

Comment: no it doesn't give correct output

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.info())` or `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1084 entries, 0 to 1083
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Fruit    1084 non-null int64
(Emptycolumn )       1084 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 17.0 KB
None

Comment: So `df.columns = ['Fruit','Count']` not working?

Comment: Yes it's working.df = df.reset_index(name='Count') Please upload as answer

Comment: There is some error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177012/discussion-between-yogesh-s-p-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by:

```
df = df.reset_index(name='Count')
```